# Rails ActiveRecord ORDER BY not respected in nested includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm encountering a strange issue. I tried to google about it but I may not be using the right wording (I am quite new at RoR).

I'm using some nested eager loading through a scope of one of my models. So I have something like this:

```
scope :includes_all, lambda {includes(
  :buggy_relation,
  :another_relation,
  an_attribute: [:first_attribute, :second_attribute])}
```

Where :buggy_relation is declared as something like this in the same model:

```
has_many :buggy_relation, -> {order(:order_index)}, class_name: 'SomeClass'
```

So, the point is, as long as I do not have `an_attribute` in my `includes()` statement, the SQL request looks correct and I can see the ORDER BY statement done on my SomeClass.order_index. But, as soon as I add the nested loading with `an_attribute: [:first_attribute, :second_attribute]`, the order of the `:buggy_relation` is not taken into account anymore. The buggy relation is obviously loaded, but nowhere is the corresponding ORDER BY stated which leads to the order not to be respected.

An example of the misbehaviour would be having a blog post with comments:

```
#EXPECTED
post -> comment 1
     -> comment 2
     -> comment 3

#OBTAINED
post -> comment 2
     -> comment 3
     -> comment 1
```

If you have any hint about this...

Answer (score 0):

So you could do the following wherever your listing through your comments

```
post.comments.order(:order_index).each do |comments|
```

Comment: Yes, but the idea here is to use the eager loading. Hence the includes. And in fact the eager loading works it is only when I add this nested loading that it does not work anymore.

The order by itself works well

Comment: Yes but when you order in the view it's already loaded and than you can order it

Comment: I get your point and you are right. Point is, I'm not primarily looking for a workaround, I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong because for what I've been able to read so far and some experiments I've made with this relation, it _should_ work. Plus, I would be a little sad to eager load a relation that should be ordered (and is without the nested property) and have to reorder it afterwards, it does not make a lot of sense. But if my use case is a non-existing one and I'm doing it totally wrong, then for sure I'll implement your suggestion.